# How to iterate through gherkin steps in scenario without browser instance restart

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I have case to check filtering in table but its not necessary to restart browser each field value check. How can I do that in loop without loosing test result for each field?

I have something like that:

```
Background: 
    Given I started app and logged in
    And I go to page with table

Scenario Outline: Filter tests
    When I clear filters
    And I filter by field value equals <FieldValue>
    Then I check if all rows has <FieldValue> in table
    
    Examples: 
    | FieldValue |
    | val1       |
    | val2       |
    | val3       |
    | val4       |
```

I want to repeat X times 'Scenario Outline' without app restart.

Driver initialize:

```
[BeforeScenario]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            Driver = _factory.Value.GetBrowser(GlobalSettings.browserType);
            var login = new Login(Driver);
            try
            {
                login.TryToLoginAgainIfUserIsNotLoggedIn(10);
            }
            catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
            {
                Driver.WebdriverCustom.Refresh();
                login.LogIn();
            }
            _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(Driver);
        }

[AfterScenario]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            try
            {
                if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status != ResultState.Success.Status)
                {
                    string filePath = Driver.Utils.TakeScreenshot();
                    TestContext.AddTestAttachment(filePath);
                    CloseAndQuit();
                }
                else
                {
                    CloseAndQuit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                string filePath = Driver.Utils.TakeScreenshot();
                TestContext.AddTestAttachment(filePath);
                CloseAndQuit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code used to initialize your web driver.

Comment: Have a look at scoped tags - you can tag your test then use specific before/after to ensure you don't close the browser each time: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Scoped-Step-Definitions.html

Comment: @RichEdwards yes, I am trying with that but I dont know how to check if is that last scenario and it should close driver in AfterScenario part

Comment: How about you put your feature in it's own scenario file and use `[AfterScenario]` or `[After]`  - those hooks run after all the scenarios in a feature files are complete.  Same concept as the other comment - isolate the logic by tagging the feature/scenarios and scope to limit the browser session

Comment: i meant `AfterFeature` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Tag your scenario with something appropriate and repeatable to track it doesn't use a new browser each iteration.

```
@SingleBrowserInstance
Scenario Outline: Filter tests
    When I clear filters
    And I filter by field value equals <FieldValue>
    Then I check if all rows has <FieldValue> in table
    
    Examples: 
    | FieldValue |
    | val1       |
 ...etc
```

For your generic catch-all `[before]`, add a constructor to the class to pull through the scenario context object then filter out this new tag. This saves you adding tags to all your other tests to compensate for this new approach.

```
[Binding]
    public class WhateverYourHooksClassIsCalled
    {
        ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
        public WhateverYourHooksClassIsCalled(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        }
   
        // This is your existing before scneario
        [BeforeScenario]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            if(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("SingleBrowserInstance"))
                return; // we don't want it to run...

            // etc...  rest of your init.
        }
}
```

Create another couple of hooks just for this tag:

```
//note this is before/after FEATURE
[BeforeFeature("SingleBrowserInstance")]
public void CleanUpSingleBrowser()
    {
        //initialise your browser. 
        // As you filter it out in the before scenario you'll need to 
        // refactor the original init into a reusable component (ask if you want help)
    }

[AfterFeature("SingleBrowserInstance")]
public void CleanUpSingleBrowser()
    {
        CleanUp();
    }
]
```

Most of the information you need is [here](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Scoped-Step-Definitions.html).

Final comment is to expect that each row of your table can impact the others. A single browser instance means that application state will now persist between tests. These tests are no longer isolated. Changing the order of the data, adding and removing data table rows can alter the overall result. Granted it's unlikely but it's something to be aware of.